# select cells by using the hlookup python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have two worksheet in excel like this , and I want to select cells by using the Hlookup with python:

data 1:

```
id       D1A      D2B   D3B   D4E   D3C   
A        1        2       5     7    4
D        4        6       6          5
B                 7       1          2
```

data 2:

```
D1      
D2   
D3   
D4
```

if I select in data2 (for example D3), I should have as results in table data1 :

```
id  D3B   D3C       
A    5      4       
D    6      5      
B    7      2
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('D3')]]`?

Comment: thank you for your response , but it's not realy what I meant (I took D3 just as an example ).  to make it more clear , I will explain in a different way : if i select in sheet 'data2' any value (D3, or D1 ...etc) I will have in sheet 'data1' the selected cells for the value chosen , so I need to code this process in python. but the manupilation will be in excel

Comment: If you want to do your manipulation in excel then this is not a pandas question. I am removing the pandas tag. You need to look up [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)